# Vector doesnt take the value I give

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, variables, integer

thanks for your help !.
the trouble is, when I run the program and give the dimension of the vector, it takes another big integer or negative value. As you can see Im using templates and it is the first time, so maybe thats the problem.
Here's the code and thanks !

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <new>
using namespace std;

template <class Tipo>
class Vector
{
   friend ostream& operator<<(ostream & COUT,const Vector<Tipo> &W)
   {
       COUT << '(';
       for(int i = 0;i < W.dim ;i++) COUT << W.V[i] << ',';
       COUT<<"\b)";
       return COUT;
   }
   friend istream& operator>>(istream & CIN,Vector<Tipo> &W)
   {
       for(int i = 0;i < W.dim ;i++){
           cout<<"Ingrese la componente " << i + 1<< " del vector." << endl;
           CIN>>*(W.V+i); // W.V[i]
       }  
       return CIN;
   }
   friend Vector operator*(Tipo esc, const Vector<Tipo> &W)
   {
       return W*esc;
   }
public:
    explicit Vector(int dim)
    {
        if(dim>0){
                V = new (nothrow) Tipo[dim];
            for(int i=0;i<dim;++i) V[i]=0;
        } 
    }
     Vector(const Vector<Tipo> &W)
     {
        dim=W.dim;
        if(dim){
            V=new (nothrow) Tipo[dim];
            for(int i=0;i<dim;++i) V[i]=W.V[i];  
        }
    }
    ~Vector()
    {
        if(V){
                dim=0;
                delete [] V;
        }
    }
    Vector operator+(const Vector<Tipo> &W) const
    {
        Vector S(dim);
        for(int i = 0;i < dim;i++){
            S.V[i] = V[i] + W.V[i];
        }
        return S;
    }
    private:
        Tipo *V;
        int dim;
    };

int main()
{
    int dim;
    float pEscalar, numEscalar;
    cout << "Programa que calcula la suma de dos vectores en R^n, n>0" << endl;
    do
    {
        cout << "n: ";
        cin >> dim;
    }while(dim <= 0);
    Vector<float> V(dim) ,W(dim),S(dim),R(dim);
    cout<<"Primer vector..." << endl;
    cin>>V;
    cout<< endl << endl << "Segundo vector..." << endl;
    cin>>W;
    S=V+W;  
    cout << endl << "La suma del primer y segundo vector es: " << endl;     
    cout<<V<<" + "<<W<<" = "<<S<<endl;
    cout << endl;    
    system("pause");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Can you cut down the code example and point to exactly where the error is? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You should get rid of your warnings before asking a question here: http://codepad.org/2auDL6wP

Comment: what does 'dimension' in your question even mean? And then which function do you want us to look at. There's too much going on here.

Comment: dimension means the size of the array, I've edited its clearer now

Comment: What do you mean by "it takes another big integer or negative value" When I do `std::cout << dim;` in `explicit Vector(int dim)` it outputs dim as expected.

Comment: exacty !!, now put `std::cout<<W.dim` in `friend istream& operator>>(istream & CIN,Vector<Tipo> &W)`  , thats suppose to print the size you give, but it prints another value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your Vector constructor that takes an int argument:

```
    explicit Vector(int dim)
    {
        if (dim>0){
            V = new (nothrow) Tipo[dim];
          for(int i=0;i<dim;++i) V[i]=0;
        } 
    }
   // So where do you assign the dim value in your object??
```

Where is dim assigned to your object?  This is what you want to do to solve your immediate issue, but I would also state that your class has other issues that need another thread of discussion.

```
    explicit Vector(int dim_) : dim(dim_)
    {
        if (dim>0){
            V = new (nothrow) Tipo[dim];
          for(int i=0;i<dim;++i) V[i]=0;
        } 
    }
```

Also, why aren't you using the debugger?  If you ran the code using a debugger, the issue should have been spotted in a matter of seconds after executing this line:

```
   Vector<float> V(dim) ,W(dim),S(dim),R(dim);
```

You would have seen that V.dim, W.dim, etc. were garbage values.

Comment: fixed !! thanks a lot im rally sorry i didnt see that